# How to export the value of useState hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use "useState" hooks in my component to set the value of the username and password input fields, then dispatch the payload (value of username and password) to a reducer that's working with redux.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {signUpUser} from "../SideBar/Redux"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import "./SignUp.css";

const SignUpModal = (props) => {
  const closeOnEscapeKeyDown = e => {
    if ((e.charCode || e.keyCode) === 27) {
      props.modalClosed();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", closeOnEscapeKeyDown);
    return function cleanup() {
      document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", closeOnEscapeKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  const [userNameInput, setUserNameInput] = useState("");
  const [userPasswordInput, setUserPasswordInput] = useState("")

  const userNameHandler = (e) => {
    setUserNameInput(e.target.value)
  }
 
  const userPasswordHandler = (e) => {
    setUserPasswordInput(e.target.value)
  }

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <CSSTransition
      in={props.isSignupModalOpened}
      unmountOnExit
      timeout={{ enter: 0, exit: 300 }}
    >
      <div className="modal" onClick={props.modalClosed}>
        <div className="modal-content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h4 className="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
              <div className = "modal-input-field">
                <div className = "modal-username-field">
                    <p className = "p-username">Username</p>
                    <input tag = "username"
                           placeholder = "eg: muhammet-aldulaimi"
                           onChange = {userNameHandler}
                      /> 
                </div>
                <div className = "modal-password-field">
                    <p className = "p-password">Password</p>
                    <input tag = "password"
                           type = "password"
                           placeholder = "eg: someStrongPassword123"
                           onChange = {userPasswordHandler}
                    /> 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className = "modal-submit"> 
                <button onClick = {props.userInfoSubmitHandler}
                        className = "modal-submit-button">Submit
                </button>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button className="button" onClick={props.modalClosed} >
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
};




const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isModalOpen: state.isModalOpen,
        isSignupModalOpened: state.isSignupModalOpened
    }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        modalOpened : () => {
            dispatch({type: "OPEN_MODAL"})
        },
        modalClosed : () => {
            dispatch({type: "CLOSE_MODAL"})
        },
        userInfoSubmitHandler: () => {
            console.log("reached prop successfully")
            console.log(userNameValue, userPasswordValue)
            dispatch(signUpUser({userName: userNameValue, userPassword: userPasswordValue}))
        }
    }
}   

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUpModal);
```

I tried exporting the variables, doesn't work. assigning the variable to another variable and then exporting it, doesn't work. I also tried passing the state variables as arguments to my prop.userInfoSubmitHandler. That also didn't work. I don't understand why are these variables not available in the scope of my userInfoSubmitHandler function. Any tips?

Comment: Can you show how you tried to pass the variables to `userInfoSubmitHandler`? Seems like that should work. What happened when you tried that?

Comment: the variables are defined within the scope of SignUpModal so they're not available outside of it aka `mapDispatchToProps` which is a sibling to SignUpModal. you said you tried passing the variables as arguments. that should work, can you show us what you tried?

Comment: When I tried to pass the localstate userNameInput and userPasswordInput as arguments to userInfoSubmitHandler function 2 things happen. 1- I have 2 modal components, a sign in and a sign up, the sign in modal component get's triggered by a button on the page and the sign up get's triggered by a button in the sign in component. I console logged the function chain one log for reaching the prop and another log for reaching the reducer. and when I click on the sign in component in order to reach the sign up component the console logs trigger twice, and when I click the submit button it doesn't...

Comment: ...trigger there when it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass as parameter onclick:

```js
<button onClick={() => props.userInfoSubmitHandler(userNameInput, userPasswordInput)}
    className = "modal-submit-button">Submit
</button>
```

Also i saw that you don't have any variable named userNameValue and userPassworValue in the state the variable names are different?

Comment: That worked!!! what was the reasoning behind this code? how come it didn't work when I tried to call it directly?

Comment: You are trying to access component's state outside of its scope. 'userInfoSubmitHandler' is a function in redux so it does not know anything about your component's state variables that's why you must pass the parameters in component.

Comment: No I already tried adding the parameters to the userInfoSubmitHandler function by doing: <button onClick={props.userInfoSubmitHandler(userNameInput, userPasswordInput)} without doing what you did which was calling a function that calls userInfoSubmitHandler like () => props.userInfoSubmitHandler.
How did yours work?

Comment: For this you can check React.js documentation: [https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)